# A question about UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

It seems that UISegmentedControl objects only send out "UIControlEventValueChanged" events.  Is it possible to make them emit "UIControlEventTouchDown" events also ?

Have tried to right click the control in IB and then connect the "UIControlEventTouchDown" event option to an IBAction method, but no event is sent out.  Have also tried to do it in code using an "action : @selector" statement but also no event.

In both cases, when I change the event to "UIControlEventValueChanged", the event is sent out as expected.

Hope that somebody who is knowledgeable on this can help ...

Comment: I'm not positive, but I doubt it. Its pretty easy to subclass/roll your own control though.

Comment: @Jesse thanks for the comment, subclassing could be a practical solution as you have suggested.  But what method should be added or overridden ...

Comment: Personally I don't ever use UISegmentControl and have made a custom UIView subclass that has 3 buttons and style them to look however I need and just have an int keep up with which one is selected and etc.

Comment: @Jesse, thanks for sharing your experience ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `addGestureRecognizer:` method inherited from `UIView`

Comment: Fortunately, the UITapGestureRecognizer object is less difficult to use and setup than it seems.  Thanks again for your answer and it's helped a lot.

Comment: It's supposed to be easy to use, right? Glad to be of assistance.